# Advanced filter/expression to limit entries

Tags: filter, excel-formula, sas, criteria

I need help with either an advanced filter or expression in either SAS EG (4.3) of Excel (2013)

I have a dataset with different breeds, father's country of origin and birth dates for pigs. I need to compare offspring born on the same date, for each breed, but entries must be limited to dates that include one international country and the birth country.

So for example.. If country B and C are international countries, for all born in January 2010, if breed 1 only has offspring from country A and breed 2 has offspring from both country A and C, only breed 2's entries will be shown for both countries. Also, there must always be one entry from country A.

So if the entries are:

Date       Country   Breed

Jan 2010     1       A

Jan 2010     1       A

Jan 2010     2       A

Jan 2010     2       C

Feb 2013     1       B

Feb 2013     1       B

I only want to only see

Date       Breed   Country

Jan 2010   2       A

Jan 2010   2       C

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: What did you try? Show us your effort. People will not do work for you.

Comment: You should be able use a combination of countif or countifs in Excel 2013 to see if they fit your criteria

Comment: I don't want to count anything though, I just want to filter it to only show certain entries for which all criteria applies.. I expect it will require an extended if function of some sort?

Comment: In SAS I have filtered for all birthdates that apply to the international animals. I then sorted to remove duplicate dates and thus only had a list of birthdates. I then re-added the full dataset and filtered to remove all breeders who didnt use international animals, limiting the number of entries. I then ran a summary table which divided that data for each breed, and then for each date it showed the animal, breeder and country. However, I cant get it to limit the birthdates to only those with both national and international animals.

Comment: .. Im guessing I may need to use an advanced filter expression but don't know enough about the advanced functions and expressions to know which to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible Excel approach. Using COUNTIFS is just a way of seeing if there is at least one case in a group with same date and breed where the following conditions are satisfied.

(1) At least one with country A (in E2):-

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,"="&A2,$B$2:$B$7,"="&B2,$C$2:$C$7,"="&C2,$D$2:$D$7,"=A")
```

(2) At least one with a different country (in F2):-

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,"="&A2,$B$2:$B$7,"="&B2,$C$2:$C$7,"="&C2,$D$2:$D$7,"<>"&D2)
```

Then combining the two conditions (in G2):-

```
=AND(E2,F2)
```

[image]

then pull the formulae down and filter on column G.

You could also do it with an array formula but I think this is easier to understand.

Comment: Hi Tom I like where you went with this... I wonder if I wont be able to do something similar in SAS. A friend of mine is pretty good at excel and shes been struggling with my problem as well but I'll send her your suggestion and see if we cant do something with it! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Tom, this has solved the problem in excel! However, I would  still love to know how to do a similar approach in SAS...

Comment: I'm glad the Excel solution helped you. I don't know how you would do it in SAS - more years than I care to admit since I used it!